# Java - Parse an input with ReplaceALL expression

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I trying to get an input to format a certain way. For example input:

Before:

```
"12/4"
```

I need a space after each letter in the string.

After:

```
" 12 / 4 "
```

Another example:

Before

```
"-10/-4*5"
```

After

```
" -10 / -4 * 5 "
```

Before

```
6*-8/(-4+2)
```

After

```
 6 * -8 / ( -4 + 2 )
```

I use the spacing to parse and split the input but if theirs not spacing then I can't split by space.

Comment: Why is there a space before the 12 but not before the -10?

Comment: Is the format always going to be <number><operator><number>etc...?

Comment: Are parenthesis possible?

Comment: Fix the space before the -10. Yes to parenthesis.

Comment: Trying to format it into infix notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can assume that `+` or `-` is not unary when there is digit or expression in parenthesis before it. Rest of operators, like `*` `/` `^` can't be unary so they always should be surrounded with spaces.

Using above assumptions you can create something like

```
String text = "-10/-4*+5+6+(1*2)-3^2";
String formatted = text.replaceAll("(?<=[\\d)])[-+]|[*/^]", " $0 ");

System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output:

```
-10 / -4 * +5 + 6 + (1 * 2) - 3 ^ 2
^^^   ^^   ^^                        these are not changed
```

Explanation: we want to surround with spaces only non-unary operators so

- `(?<=[\\d)])[-+]` - we are checking if before `-` or `+` there is any digit or `)` using [look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `(?<=[\\d)])`
- `[*/^]` we accept any of `*`, `/`, `^` as non-unary symbols which need to be surrounded by spaces - you can add here more symbols if you like for example `(` `)`.
- `" $0 "` - here `$0` represents match from group 0 (match from entire regex) so we are simply replacing operator found by regex with the same operator but surrounded with spaces.

Comment: is possible to get parenthesis to be space as well? For example 6*-8/(-4+2) = 6 * -8 / ( -4 + 2 )

Comment: @user3590149 yes, just add them to `[*/^]` section like `[*/^()]`

Comment: Also if its positive, don't add + to it? Could I change this from (?<=[\\d)])[-+] to (?<=[\\d)])[-] ? Would this work?

Comment: @user3590149 Yes, you could even skip `[` `]` in `[-]`. So you could just use `(?<=[\\d)])-`. But you need to place `+` you removed to `[*/^]` part because you most probably want to surround it with spaces. So regex can look like `(?<=[\\d)])-|[+*/^()]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this (see the substitutions in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/fS8mF0/4)):

```
String replaced = yourString.replaceAll("-?\\d+|.", "$0 ");
```

Note: I am assuming the space before the 12 is a typo, as you said you want to insert spaces after the tokens.

**Explanation**

- `-?\d+` matches an optional hyphen and digits
- `|` OR
- `.` matches a character
- `$0` replaces with the match and a space character

Answer (score 0):

On that case, you dont have to use space, use other character :

As i can see on your example, you can try the operator as your split argument like `+` ,`-`,`*`,`/`.

So you can use like this :

```
str.split("+|-|*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(-?\d+)([^\d])` and replace it with `$1 $2` (not sure if that should be $0 & $1, I could be off by one).

This finds a number followed by a non-number (`[^\d]` could be replaced with `[/*+-^etc]` to only match specific operators) and captures each separately, then replaces them with the first capture, a space, and then the second capture.